# Need help to make sqlcmd run as per requirements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, cmd, sqlcmd

I wanted to run SQLCMD.EXE as mentioned here - http://blog.daringa.com/archives/tag/error-hresult-e_fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component

I used the line in link with proper path to sqlcmd, user and password I use to login to my SQL server - `sqlcmd -S .\MYSQLSERVER2008 -U MyUsername -P MyPassword -i C:\Database\hugescript.sql`

Problem - I see a window and some message, but it vanishes so quickly that I cannot even see what it is. How do I see this window and how do I then execute an SQL file via SQLCMD.EXE

Why am I executing a script via SQLCMD and not SQL SERVER (ie SS) MGMT STUDIO ? 
SS throws an error when sql files are big, ie about 100mb or more.

Comment: Check your server name, check if SQL Server service is startup, check your username, check your password, check hugescript.sql is exists in C:\Database. Try connect to your SQL using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @IswantoSan - Cannot use studio. Studio throws an error when sql files are big, ie about 100mb or more. Need to use only sqlcmd,exe

Comment: What happen if you run the sqlcmd with small file? Try to create a .sql file and then run it with sqlcmd

Comment: @IswantoSan - same thing. Black screen comes and goes quickly. I cannot read the message.

Comment: Run it from cmd. Open new command prompt window and type your command in there. Or try Szymon trick to get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output from `sqlcmd`

```
sqlcmd -S .\MYSQLSERVER2008 -U MyUsername -P MyPassword 
-i C:\Database\hugescript.sql > log.txt 2> error.txt
```

It will write the output to `log.txt` file and errors to `error.txt` file (you can specify the full path if you want). You can then see what's happening.

Comment: You can redirect it like this `> C:\log.txt 2> C:\error.txt`. The file will be generated in C:\

Comment: I ran the command and looked for error and log file in same folder. found nothing.

Comment: If you don't specify the full path, in the same folder you're running your sqlcmd from. But you can specify full path, e.g. `> c:\temp\log.txt 2> c:\temp\error.txt`

Comment: @Szymon - my bad. i was entering this into run of windows and not cmd.exe. that is why it was not working.

Comment: Okay, filename has spaces also. That causes error which i saw in error.txt - invalid file name. fixed that by putting file path in double quotes

Comment: @Szymon - now, error = Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Operation was canceled. Log = Canceling connection. Please wait...

Comment: I suggest you create a separate question for that problem as this question is about seeing the output of sqlcmd.

Comment: @Szymon - I made another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674377/need-to-understand-output-of-sqlcmd-exe