# Need to understand output of sqlcmd.exe

Tags: sql-server, windows, cmd, sqlcmd

I was advised to make another question, from here - [Need help to make sqlcmd run as per requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674045/need-help-to-make-sqlcmd-run-as-per-requirements)

My sqlcmd.exe is invoked with a command of the form -

```
sqlcmd -S .\MYSQLSERVER2008 -U MyUsername -P MyPassword 
-i C:\Database\hugescript.sql > log.txt 2> error.txt
```

Now,

```
log.txt says - Canceling connection. Please wait...
Error.txt says - Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : 
Operation was canceled..
```

How do I find out the cause of the problem and fix it ?

Comment: would it be better to post this on serverfault or superuser instead ?

Comment: great, superuser banned me long ago and wont allow me in. everything else allows me.

Comment: Did you hit Ctrl+C by any chance? Or the "Close" button on the console window?